# Is it possible to build an online application which can dynamically render 3D objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm investigating the possibility to be able to render 3D objects in a web application. Imagine I have a 3D cube looking something like the left in the figure below.

[image: example]

I then want a slider that sets a threshold value of what to be rendered. Let's say the value was to be set to 1.2. Then I would want only the red parts of the cube to be visible, like to the right in the figure. I also (of course) want to be able to rotate the object freely.

In the figure the cube consists of points in a grid, but I would like a nice looking model out of it instead, like an isosurface.

Is this possible to achieve in an online application via React or something alike? I've read a bit about Three.js but I have only seen usages of pre-made models.

So in short, what I'm asking is if it is possible to go from points -> model -> view, ideally without having to reload the page.

Comment: Have a look at WebGL: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API

Comment: I might have something that I'll consider open sourcing,  what's the resolution of your the grid data?

Comment: @visibleman Cool, it's about 200x200x150

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [project](https://www.nationalgeographic.com/science/2016/11/exploring-mars-map-panorama-pictures/), it's made with [Three.js](https://threejs.org/), on its site you will find more detailed information, but I would recommend creating the model in a 3D program like Blender and then playing with the textures and geometries to achieve the desired effect.

Also check out [OrbitControls](https://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_orbit.html), a very simple tool to explore your 3D scene

I did [this project](https://joseluismurillorios.github.io/rexrage/) that responds to the microphone, it's a bit messy but you can play with it and find other projects on my [github](https://github.com/joseluismurillorios/rexrage)